# How to get all children (and their subchildren) in a yaml file using snakeyaml

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

So I have been across with [snakeyaml](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml). I know how to get
their keys using
`java
yaml.load(inputStream);`

That would return a hashmap of a String and an Object.
Just for demonstration I have a yaml file with values:

```
player:
  randie:
    score: 4
```

When I use

```
File file = new File("test")
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

Map<String, Object> map = yaml.load(stream);

for (String str : map.keySet()) {
   System.out.println(map.get(str));
}
```

The output would be:

```
{randie={score=4}}
```

I came across other stackoverflow questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744919/how-to-access-the-innernested-key-value-in-an-yaml-file-using-snakeyaml-librar)

I wanted to get a value in the innermost "nested" value without using a list of hashmaps provided by [the correct answer in the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48744919/how-to-access-the-innernested-key-value-in-an-yaml-file-using-snakeyaml-librar)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create classes that represent the structure of the yaml file and then load it in the correct format.

```
public class Result {
    private Player player;

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    } 
}

public class Player {
    private Randie randie;

    public Randie getRandie() {
        return randie;
    }

    public void setRandie(Randie randie) {
        this.randie = randie;
    } 
}

public class Randie {
    private int score;

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    } 
}
```

and then load it using the `loadAs` function.

```
public class YamlDataInterpreter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YamlDataInterpreter intepreter = new YamlDataInterpreter();
        intepreter.interpretYaml();
    }

    public void interpretYaml() {
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("data.yml");

        Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        Result res = yaml.loadAs(stream, Result.class);
        System.out.println(res.getPlayer().getRandie().getScore());
    }
}
```

https://github.com/KenavR/snakeyaml-example

Comment: Thanks, though right now I am making a "SimpleYaml". I don't really need objects though!

Comment: Then you can look into Reflection

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989560/how-to-get-the-fields-in-an-object-via-reflection
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html

or just read in the string and extract the value manually.

Comment: Yep. Reflection is an api for accessing classes, fields, and methods in code. Though maybe you didn't understand what I said. I needed to get a value without making a class.
Basically, read from a file. This will save memory space

Comment: I did understand it, but reflection isn't really something I would recommend for a beginner. If you already know of reflection, what do you need then? Someone implementing it with reflection? Are you working on a resource constraint system? If yes, why load a library in the first place? Why not just work with the string?

Comment: ahh Thanks anyways. I just need to create a parser class, I guess. Again, thanks for help